# Is there a replacement for Rosetta in Lion?

Tags: powerpc, rosetta

I have a few PowerPC Mac binaries I would like to run under MacOSX 10.7.

I guess Rosetta is not going to be Open Source, isn't it? Any petition about this? I would start one or contact someone at Apple about this if I would know whom or where.

Can Rosetta be downloaded somewhere or copied over from an 10.6 and made working on 10.7?

Then I thought about user the userspace QEMU emulation. This would be the same thing as what Rosetta was doing (right?). However, from [here](http://wiki.qemu.org/download/qemu-doc.html#Mac-OS-X_002fDarwin-User-space-emulator), it says

> - target PowerPC on x86: Not working as the ppc commpage can’t be mapped (yet!)

I'm not sure what that means. I would like to work on this if this isn't too hard but not sure where to start. (Btw., because of this, maybe this question is better suited for Stackoverflow?)

[Here](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/qemu-devel/2007-03/msg00520.html) is a mail from the mailinglist (from 2007) with some more information (not much though).

What are other possibilities?

Comment: If you're going to petition Apple it might be more successful to ask them to change the Snow Leopard EULA to allow virtualization. It is allowed for the server version, but that is a bit expensive.

Answer (score 2):

I know it sucks, but really you might just need to drop the PPC stuff (Apple isn't going to support it at all in the future) or look into trying to get the source code and recompiling it yourself.

Comment: I know but that was not my question.

Comment: That's why I added that you might have to look at contacting whomever the binary is from, getting the source, and seeing if you can recompile it. As far as I'm aware, there are no other options other than Rosetta for doing what you are asking.

Comment: Yea but that is also not my question. I really want to run PPC code (or know about that here).

Comment: SheepShaver is for running Mac OS 9 and previous on OS X, not OS X on OS X, so probably won't help you. I don't believe Rosetta can be easily implemented in Lion, since it is most probably tied very deeply in the OS. Perhaps we could help you find alternatives to your PPC binaries?

Comment: @Fred: No, Rosetta not tied very deeply in the OS. It's all userland. And if I would like to find alternatives to some PPC apps, I would open another question for that, but here, I really want to know about possibilities to run PPC binaries.

Comment: @Albert: I don't agree that Rosette is not tied deeply in the OS. Somehow it has to be, because when you launch an app, the OS probably redirected the task to Rosetta to finish the job, so if it were not integrated in the OS, how would it know where to send it? And also, I don't think that Rosetta is only a faceless background app, it has to be more than that. But anyways, did some research on the web, looks like no one has found a solution yet.

Answer (score 2):

At this point, the open source PPC Mac emulator [Sheepshaver](http://sheepshaver.cebix.net/) may be your best bet.

Comment: "Runs MacOS 7.5.2 thru 9.0.4. MacOS X as a guest is not supported." Hmm...

Answer (score 1):

Install Snow Leopard (and Rosetta) in Parallels 7 in Lion.  Installation guide here:

http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1365439